# Transmission cannot be started in Unix

Tags: unix, transmission

I once opened Transmission in some computer in the computer centre of my institute, and maybe forgot to exit Transmission and locked the screen. Then on some later day I log in from another computer in the computer centre, and whenever I try to open Transmission from some computer I get a message box with the following message:

```
Transmission is already running,but not responding. 
To start a new session you must first close existing Transmission process.
```

I have tried the command: `kill -9 transmisson`. I tried `top`, but that also didn't show any Transmission ID. I know how to get rid of it in the case of Firefox. The command for Firefox is `rm -rf .mozilla/`, but in the case of other applications, I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see the process because it is running on a different machine.

You should stop it on the same machine you started the process.

**Edit**

BTW try first a clean shutdown with `kill` without the `-9`. Otherwise the open lock files will not be removed.

Comment: But I think it has got frozen. Now every computer is showing the same pop up.

Comment: The pop up appears since transmission is detecting some lock files. Did you check on every machine if the process is running?

Comment: kill or kill -9 gives following. 
bash: kill: transmission: arguments must be process or job IDs

That is why I tried "top" to find Id. but didn't find transmission there

Comment: Either use `killall transmission` or find out the PID (process ID) with `ps` and then `kill PID`

Comment: the problem still persists. here is the output of the commands
$ ps
Output:"  PID TTY          TIME CMD
14241 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
14547 pts/0    00:00:00 ps"
$ killall transmission
output:transmission: no process killed
$ kill 14241
$ kill 14547
output:bash: kill: (14547) - No such process